# JOtionpane and control structure

Tags: java

please help me, i know its too easy but i cant answer it, waaah, i think i have an headache now, the problem was:

Prompt the user for a message and ask how many times to print it.
your program output should be as follows:

How will you like me to print?
How many times do you want me to print it?

---

and my prof told us that we should use JOptionPane and control structure for the two question, and the answer should be in System.out.println..
please help me, thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

You will want to use `JOptionPane#showInputDialog` to get the information from the user, you will need to do this (at least) twice, once to get the message and once to the count.

You could use a `do-while` to ensure that the user enters a valid, numerical value...

```
int count = 0;
do {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
    try {
        count = Integer.parseInt(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        // You could show a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog here as an error message
    }
} while (count != 0);
```

Once you have all the information, you will could use a `for-loop` to print the result...

Take a look at:

- [`JOptionPane` Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)
- [The for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

For more details

Comment: +1 You even linked to the documentation of the `for` statement :)